# PHP - Regex to find [digit][digit][colon][digit][digit]

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to extract [digit][digit][colon][digit][digit] from a string if it is present. The Regex should match:

```
02:59
03:24
```

So far I've got quite lost, though I've realised `\d` will return me a single digit, and `\d{2}` should find me 2, but I've got stuck with adding in the separator `:` and finding 2 more digits to fit into my `preg_match`:

`$trackTime = preg_match($regexEludingMe, $track, $matches);`

Example `$track` is: 
`10. Break Your Heart 03:42` should match `03:42`

Comment: Just keep it going: `\d{2}:\d{2}`

Comment: Brill. Apologies for basically wasting your time. Add as an answer and I'll accept. Bear in mind I forgot the delimiters. In summary: `'/\d{2}:\d{2}/'` matches.

Comment: @JMB Deleting the question is also an option if you think it is useless.

Comment: True. Maybe a lesson to future Googlers in carrying on down the path you're on before asking for help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the separator `:` and duplicate the first part that you've already figured out `\d{2}:\d{2}`.  Don't forget delimiters:

```
 preg_match('/\d{2}:\d{2}/', $track, $trackTime);

 print_r($trackTime);
```